# Convert XML to/from JSON in Java (without extra <e> and <o> elements)

Tags: java, xml, json

I am using the XMLSerializer found in the json-lib library, in order to transform between JSON  and XML and back.

Is there anyway to avoid the `<e>` and `<a>` nodes, that are generated? This is very inconveniently ruining by path-expressions?

Consider the example below:

```
{"store": {
  "book":   [
        {
      "category": "reference",
      "author": "Nigel Rees",
      "title": "Sayings of the Century",
      "price": 8.95
    },
        {
      "category": "fiction",
      "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
      "title": "Sword of Honour",
      "price": 12.99
    },
        {
      "category": "fiction",
      "author": "Herman Melville",
      "title": "Moby Dick",
      "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
      "price": 8.99
    },
        {
      "category": "fiction",
      "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
      "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
      "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
      "price": 22.99
    }
  ],
  "bicycle":   {
    "color": "red",
    "price": 19.95
  }
}}
```

Is serialised into:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<o>
  <store class="object">
    <bicycle class="object">
      <color type="string">red</color>
      <price type="number">19.95</price>
    </bicycle>
    <book class="array">
      <e class="object">
        <author type="string">Nigel Rees</author>
        <category type="string">reference</category>
        <price type="number">8.95</price>
        <title type="string">Sayings of the Century</title>
      </e>
      <e class="object">
        <author type="string">Evelyn Waugh</author>
        <category type="string">fiction</category>
        <price type="number">12.99</price>
        <title type="string">Sword of Honour</title>
      </e>
      <e class="object">
        <author type="string">Herman Melville</author>
        <category type="string">fiction</category>
        <isbn type="string">0-553-21311-3</isbn>
        <price type="number">8.99</price>
        <title type="string">Moby Dick</title>
      </e>
      <e class="object">
        <author type="string">J. R. R. Tolkien</author>
        <category type="string">fiction</category>
        <isbn type="string">0-395-19395-8</isbn>
        <price type="number">22.99</price>
        <title type="string">The Lord of the Rings</title>
      </e>
    </book>
  </store>
</o>
```

Something like what this **http://jsontoxml.utilities-online.info/** provides would have been exactly what I’m after, but don’t seem to be available in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [StAXON](http://beckchr.github.com/staxon/) - JSON via StAX. StAXON implements the Streaming API for XML, but reads and writes JSON. That is, you can use standard XML tools to do the Job.

A common "trick" to copy XML is using an identity XML transformation (XSLT).

Here's some code:

```
InputStream input = ... // your JSON input;
OutputStream output = System.out;
try {
    /*
     * Create source.
     */
    XMLInputFactory inputFactory = new JsonXMLInputFactory();
    inputFactory.setProperty(JsonXMLInputFactory.PROP_MULTIPLE_PI, false);
    Source source = new StAXSource(inputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(input));

    /*
     * Create result.
     */
    XMLOutputFactory outputFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
    XMLStreamWriter writer = outputFactory.createXMLStreamWriter(output);
    writer = new PrettyXMLStreamWriter(writer); // format output
    Result result = new StAXResult(writer);

    /*
     * Transform (copy).
     */
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    transformerFactory.newTransformer().transform(source, result);
} finally {
    /*
     * As per StAX specification, XMLStreamReader/Writer.close() doesn't close
     * the underlying stream.
     */
    output.close();
    input.close();
}
```

Running this with your example produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<store>
    <book>
        <category>reference</category>
        <author>Nigel Rees</author>
        <title>Sayings of the Century</title>
        <price>8.95</price>
    </book>
    <book>
        <category>fiction</category>
        <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
        <title>Sword of Honour</title>
        <price>12.99</price>
    </book>
    <book>
        <category>fiction</category>
        <author>Herman Melville</author>
        <title>Moby Dick</title>
        <isbn>0-553-21311-3</isbn>
        <price>8.99</price>
    </book>
    <book>
        <category>fiction</category>
        <author>J. R. R. Tolkien</author>
        <title>The Lord of the Rings</title>
        <isbn>0-395-19395-8</isbn>
        <price>22.99</price>
    </book>
    <bicycle>
        <color>red</color>
        <price>19.95</price>
    </bicycle>
</store>
```

Note: If the output property `PROP_MULTIPLE_PI` is set to `true`, StAXON will generate `<xml-multiple>` processing instructions. These can be used by StAXON when converting back to JSON to trigger array starts. Leave this set to `false` if you don't need to go back to JSON.

Comment: @-chris which version of stAXON to be used and inputstream we can give filename as input or only string and Result result = new StAXResult(writer); here it is showing error to convert Result to staxresult and output is not proper

Comment: @user1182090 using staxon-1.0. You can use any Reader/InputStream and Writer/OutputStream (e.g. FileReader/Writer). If you have problems with StAXResult, you can also use the StAX event API. See https://github.com/beckchr/staxon/wiki/Converting-JSON-to-XML

Comment: @-chris, ur code working fine, but now i am reading from a json file and creating xml using ur code, but how can i convert valid json file into a obj and from that obj i should print xml...

Comment: @user1182090 take a look at JAXB. You can do this with StAXON too, see https://github.com/beckchr/staxon/wiki/Using-JAXB. Anyway, this is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: if I have an xml <errorCode>5</errorCode> and want to convert as json object like "errorCode": "5" (not : 5), how to force this to not be a number?